# Error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism-6

I'm using the VS For Mac Community (v7.2.2) and my Xamarin Project have as target .NET Standard 2.0. I'm having this error while trying to build the project.

> Error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,

I was try to set up the referenced, but does not works.The project that presents error is iOS.
How can I solve this problem?
Would anyone like to help me, please?

Comment: Here's a similar case, you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257471/cs0012-system-enum-is-defined-in-an-assembly-not-referenced-on-build-server-targ

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the .NET Core SDK? You will need this installed to build .NET standard apps.

You can download the installer from:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm using .NET Core SDK 2.0.0 // .NET Core Runtime 2.0.0.